# 4 AAA 1,5 volt vs 5v 300mah dc power supply

Tags: power-supply, batteries, dc, 5v

I have an LED-Lamp which has 4 x AAA 1.5 in it. IIII is the layout of series of the batteries.

I would like to attach a dc power supply of 5V 300mah 1.5VA.

Would this be to much for the LED and eventually (days/weeks I mean) burn it out?

Or would it not be enough (if I do 4 x 1.5 = 6v?) to power it?

Comment: As you say, 4 fully charged AAA cells give 6V. However, lamps are often  designed to work with discharged cells of 1V each (ie 4V). So a 5V supply will work, but perhaps not as bright as with new cells.

Comment: I've soldered the whole thing and indeed it works. It is bright and I see the point of the led being yellowish/reddish bright. Though no smoke after 5 minutes..

Answer (score 1):

The 5 volt supply should work.  The lamp probably woon't be quite as bright as with fresh AAA cells, but the AAA cells would drop to, or below, 5 volts with use, so even with batteries, the lamp won't maintain full brightness.